# Parse a multi dimensional array and pull values

Tags: php, arrays

How can i parse the below multi dimensional array (`$array`) and pull values of `[productType]` , `[totalPrice]`and `[productCategory]` if `[packageCode]` is matching with the value of `$pkgcodes[1]...[z]`
`$pkgcodes` is an array of codes

print_r of `$pkgcodes`

```
Array ( [0] => TRA1I2 [1] => TREZEC [n] ...)
```

The array `$array` is a response from SOAP client

print_r of `$array`

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
    [packageCode] => TRA1I2 
    [totalPrice] => 17 
    [productType] => product Only 
    [products] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [productCategory] => Simple 
            [paxes] => Array ( 
                [0] => Array ( 
                    [paxType] => Adult 
                    [age] => 30 ) 
                    [1] => Array ( 
                        [paxType] => Adult 
                        [age] => 30 ) ) 
                        [totalproductRate] => 17 
                        [ratesPerNight] => Array ( 
                            [0] => Array ( 
                                [date] => 2015-01-28 
                                [amount] => 17 ) ) ) ) ) 
[1] => Array ( 
    [packageCode] => TREZEC 
    [totalPrice] => 17 
    [productType] => product Only 
    [products] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [productCategory] => Complicated 
            [paxes] => Array ( 
                [0] => Array ( 
                    [paxType] => Adult 
                    [age] => 30 ) 
                    [1] => Array ( 
                        [paxType] => Adult 
                        [age] => 30 ) ) 
                        [totalproductRate] => 17 
                        [ratesPerNight] => Array ( 
                            [0] => Array ( 
                            [date] => 2015-01-28 
                            [amount] => 17 ) ) ) ) ) ).
```

You help is more appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
$newArr = array();
foreach($array as $value) {
   if (in_array($value['packageCode'], $pkgcodes)) {
       $temp['productType'] = $value['productType'];
       $temp['totalPrice'] = $value['totalPrice'];
       $temp['packageCode'] = $value['packageCode'];
       $temp['productCategory'] = $value['products']['productCategory'];
       $newArr[] = $temp;
   }
}
var_dump($newArr);
```